# Tutorial To learn about java mobile application development

Tags: java

I want to develop java mobile applications.I could not find the best tutorial.Can any one guide me to the best and easiest tutorial.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you mean Java ME, or Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**J2ME**

1.http://www.j2meforums.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorials
2.[http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430_*J2ME/Catalog0430*_J2ME.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/Catalog0430__J2ME.htm)
3.http://developers.sun.com/mobility/learn/midp/getstart/

Answer (score 3):

You may want to develop Mobile Java Application using Codename ONE a cross-platform Java Mobile development platform.
Getting Started : http://www.codenameone.com/getting-started.html
Developer Resources: http://www.codenameone.com/developers.html

The cool thing here is that you will end up writing one code and with a click of a button you can cross compile mobile applications for almost any device.

Answer (score 2):

You could use my answer here in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869338/where-to-start-to-learn-android/2869373#2869373

There I listed a lot of resources for starting developing in Android.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a starting point Java Mobile ... [Tutorial](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wtoolkit/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in:

- Java Apps for Android
- Html5 for smartphones with modern browser served by a Java-based Web Server
- J2ME

The most fun is Android - you should start with the link from Roflcoptr. If you are interested in covering a lot of devices around the world, go for Html5. If you need native device capability like geo location, investigate some time into [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/). IMHO, J2ME isn't very sexy for developers, but it is used by Blackberry and Nokia and a lot of existing devices are running these mobile OS.

Answer (score 0):

You may dive in to Android Development. http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To learn programming on java for android you can try to use StartJava

http://www.en.assoft.ru/startjava